# JSON deserialization with Jackson YAML: Invalid Object id definition; Cannot find property

Tags: io, jackson, yaml

I'm trying to implement an IO system which saves the running class themselves without separate save types for each class. So far I've succeeded in:

- Writing data to YML files
- Reading data from YML files

Jackson YAML library is being used to handle serialization and deserialization.

However, I'm having a problem using the @JsonIdentityInfo annotaion. (while trying to solve the issue of circular referencing) The official docs suggest that I can specify a parameter to be the identifier for that object. Hence, I specified a UUID named uniqueId to handle this.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type"
)

@JsonSerialize(
        as = EconomicActor.class // I have also tried removing this annotation
)

@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Company.class, name = "company"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = NaturalPerson.class, name = "person"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Sovereignty.class, name = "sovereignty"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Trust.class, name = "trust")
})

@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "uniqueId"
)

public interface Actor
```

The type hierarchy works like this:

```
- Actor (interface)
-- EconomicActor (abstract class)
--- NaturalPerson (final class)
--- Company (final class)
--- Trust (final class)
--- Sovereignty (final class)
```

And EconomicActor contains the following code which is inherited to each final class

```
@JsonProperty("uniqueId") // I have also tried removing the explicit field name
private final UUID uniqueId;
```

Yet when I try to load the YML, this happens:

Invalid Object Id definition for `oasis.economyx.actor.Actor`: cannot find property with name 'uniqueId'

I have tried moving the @JsonProperty tag around to different levels of the type hierarchy, and putting the annotation in the getUniqueId() getters. I have also tried loading with the abstract class instead of the interface:

Before:

```
actors.add(mapper.readValue(f, Actor.class));
```

After:

```
actors.add(mapper.readValue(f, EconomicActor.class));
```

None of which have changed the error message.

I suspected that somehow the uniqueId was not being recognized as a parameter by Jackson.

Here is the output file:

```
--- !<company>
&e3d5bd15-184e-4dbc-80dd-291acb2d1f42 uniqueId: "e3d5bd15-184e-4dbc-80dd-291acb2d1f42"
name: "Oasis Corporation"
portfolio: !<asset_portfolio>
  assets:
  - !<stock_stack>
    asset: !<stock>
      &f664c429-fe72-4adc-8ed1-81046109707a uniqueId: "f664c429-fe72-4adc-8ed1-81046109707a"
      type: "STOCK"
    quantity: 100
    meta: !<stock_meta> {}
    type: "STOCK"
assets: !<asset_portfolio>
  assets:
  - !<stock_stack>
    asset: !<stock>
      &f664c429-fe72-4adc-8ed1-81046109707a uniqueId: "f664c429-fe72-4adc-8ed1-81046109707a"
      type: "STOCK"
    quantity: 100
    meta: !<stock_meta> {}
    type: "STOCK"
type: "COMPANY"
```

Comment: Not a desirable solution, but found a way around the issue:

Use UUIDGenerator instead

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class)